# How to allow global connections

Tags: python, network-programming

I want that the below code should also accept the connections comming from the outside network. It is accepting only local network connections
Code:

```
import socket

def run_server():
        # create a socket object
        server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        server_ip = "127.0.0.1"
        port = 8000

        # bind the socket to a specific address and port
        server.bind((server_ip, port))
        # listen for incoming connections
        server.listen(0)
        print(f"Listening on {server_ip}:{port}")

        # accept incoming connections
        client_socket, client_address = server.accept()
        print(f"Accepted connection from {client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]}")

        # receive data from the client
        while True:
            request = client_socket.recv(1024)
            request = request.decode("utf-8")  # convert bytes to string

            # if we receive "close" from the client, then we break
            # out of the loop and close the connection
            if request.lower() == "close":
                    # send response to the client which acknowledges that the
                    # connection should be closed and break out of the loop
                    client_socket.send("closed".encode("utf-8"))
                    break

            print(f"Received: {request}")

            response = "accepted".encode("utf-8")  # convert string to bytes
            # convert and send accept response to the client
            client_socket.send(response)

        # close connection socket with the client
        client_socket.close()
        print("Connection to client closed")
        # close server socket
        server.close()

run_server()
```

I was Trying a port Forwarding also but it didn't worked. I have done the port forwading from my router to my pc.
but it is working only in local network not from the public to local.

Comment: your code seems fine. however, you can test the server setup with an outside connection IP by running the server code on a machine accessible from the outside network. Then, use a client (like another computer or script) from a different network to connect to the server by specifying the server's public IP address and the port number used in the server code. But remember to configure firewall settings and ensure proper security measures before exposing services to external networks.

Comment: Change `server_ip = "127.0.0.1"` to `server_ip = "0.0.0.0"`. 127.0.0.1 means that the server only listens to the loopback interface. 0.0.0.0  means to accept traffic from all of the available interfaces

Comment: Maurice Meyer it also does not worked i have changed my server address to 0.0.0.0 . Can you please tell me which ip address i should keep in the client connection my router's gateway or router's internet ip address